# How to string lines from the_content() hook in WordPress?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions, hooks

Inside my content-video.php template, I have the following codes:

```
<iframe src="<?php echo get_the_content(); ?>" width="960" height="540" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

The `<?php echo get_the_content(); ?>` string the whole content which is normally a video link posted by the user and then embed with a frame.

I would like to string only the First line which is normally the link and then display what's below the link into the post. Is their some way of doing so?

Basically the codes should the be something like this:

```
<iframe src="<?php echo get_the_content('Line 1'); ?>" width="960" height="540" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>

<?php echo get_the_content('Line 2 & Below'); ?>
```

Comment: The best way to do this would probably be using a regular expression to extract the URL. This isn't exactly WP related, so do a search on getting URLs via regular expressions and see if that helps :)

Comment: I can't find any topic which can help me to get URL from the content and get the text only :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038061/regular-expression-to-find-urls-within-a-string and http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php should give something to start with

Comment: Is there a reason why the URL has to be the first line in the content, and not a custom field?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Nope I must just extract the URL from the post and extract the text from the post.

Comment: Yes, and I ask _why_ are you doing that, as opposed to using a custom field?

Comment: I don't know any other way, I just need the URL to place into the <iframe> and the Display the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know any other way

There is a much, **much** better way to do this - custom fields.

[image: Custom Fields]

As per [these instructions in the custom fields docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields#Usage), let's say you use the field name `iframe_url`:

```
<iframe src="<?php echo esc_url( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'iframe_url', true ) ?>" width="960" height="540" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>

<?php the_content() ?>
```

See how much cleaner that is? You've separated *data* from *content*; no nasty regular expressions or string hacking.